# Reading / writing to entity field using name stored in variable

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a winforms application which uses Linq to SQL.  One of my database tables has a number of fields like this...

```
Area_1
Area_2
Area_3...
```

I need to be able to access these fields dynamically at runtime.  I have a number of wired up buttons on my form which correspond to the different areas, so I created a string like this...

```
String sField = String.Format("Area_{0}", myAreaNumber);
```

And need to be able to read / write to the specific field using this variable. At this stage, I have already grabbed the entity object I need to work with.  How can I go about using the 'sField' variable to read / write to a field?

Comment: You can read, not write, with [dynamic linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Can't you use standard linq to sql methods to write to the database?

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully clarify what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

You can run raw SQL directly on database using `SqlQuery` method on `DbSet`:

```
context.YourDbSet.SqlQuery("query string")
```

Comment: is there no way to do this after the query has already run?  When I have the dataset?

Comment: You can use [`CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to run the string as code on-the-fly. Hope this helps.